# Dynamic type casting at runtime

Tags: objective-c

I have a category for `NSManagedObjectContext` , which inserts an `NSManagedObject` in another `NSManagedObjectContext` and returns item:

```
@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (GTEntity)

- (id)addEntity:(id)entity {
     NSManagedObject *entityObject = [self objectWithID:[entity objectID]];
     return entityObject;
}

@end
```

My question is how I return object the same type as I've got. I mean, if I call `[ctx addEntity:city]` with `City *city`, where the City is a `NSManagedObject` subclass, I would like to get the object in other context but the same type, not in `NSManagedObject` type. This type is generic and should be determinated at the runtime from entity, like `objc_getClass(entity)`. I found some macros, but it has some strange errors `Expected "]"` after `(cls *)`:

```
#define objc_dynamic_cast(obj, cls) \
([obj isKindOfClass:(Class)objc_getClass(#cls)] ? (cls *)obj : NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `City *city = [someManagedObjectContext addEntity:someCityObject];` assuming `City` derives from `NSManagedObject`.  Your return variable will have been dynamically casted.  Though I don't believe there is anything to be gained from making a category out of it, you could just do it directly like so:

```
City *city = [someManagedObjectContext objectWithID:[someCityObject objectID]];
```